# React, Sass, getting an error when importing img from a .scss file

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to set a simple background image with an overlay to a react component from a sass file, but I am getting this error, `Module not found: You attempted to import ../assets/hero.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`, this is very strange as the assets folder that contains the image is actually inside the `/src` folder,  here is my folder structure

```js
src/ 
  |assets/
          hero.jpg
  |sass/
        |main.scss
        |sassFiles/
                  |components.scss
                  |..
  |components/
             |Navbar.js
             |Home.js
             |..
  |App.js
  |index.js
  |..
```

```css
/* _components.scss file */

.hero {
  height: 60vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.459)), url(../../assets/hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

when I import the image from the component like so `import hero from '../assets/hero.jpg'`, it works fine,
the error occurs only when I import it from the .scss file, other than that, styles are being applied with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What error are you seeing in the web inspector? Trying changing the relative path to your image from:

```
url(../../assets/hero.jpg)
```

To:

```
url(../assets/hero.jpg)
```

Comment: this takes me to the `/sass` folder only, so i still need to go back one more step to the `src/` then enter the assets folder, in short, I am still getting the same error. thanks anyway.

Comment: You are importing your components.scss file in your main.scss file, so this is the correct answer.

Comment: You are correct, thanks very much, sorry for the late response, cheers :)

Comment: I keep forgetting that all the partial files get compiled into one big scss file in the main.scss, so indeed the path is ../