# Responsive flex boxes with sass and controlling images overflow

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, responsive-design, flexbox

**Dublicate part**

I am trying to build a certain layout for a section in React application, the layout is similar to this image below, *Ignore the lines on the right*.
[image]
here is my HTML, 
the boxes are empty for the moment, back to that later..

```html
const projects = () => {
  return (
    <section className="projects">
      <div className="container fcontainer">
        <div className="fcol fcol--1">
          <div className="box-1"></div>
          <div className="box-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="fcol fcol--2">
          <div className="box-1"></div>
          <div className="box-1"></div>
          <div className="box-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="fcol fcol--3">
          <div className="box-1"></div>
          <div className="box-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Now here is my .scss code

```css
.fcol {
    color: #333;
    margin: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 60vh;
    flex-grow: 4;

    &--1 {
      .box-1{
        background-color: lightblue;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
      } 
      
      .box-2{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        flex-grow: 2;
      }
    }

    &--2 {
      .box-1{
        background-color: lightblue;
        flex-grow: 1;
        justify-content: space-between;
        &:not(:last-child){
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }
      } 
    }

    &--3 {
      .box-1{
        background-color: lightblue;
        flex-grow: 3;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
      } 
      
      .box-2{
        background-color: lightgreen;
        flex-grow: 2;
      }
    }
  }
```

and here is the result..[image]

this is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXXLpG?editors=1100) for you guys to edit and fix the issue if you are interested, also feel free to change the HTML and scss entire structure if you have a better approach.

**the Non-dublicate part**
I am a little stuck in populating each box with an image as the image always overflow outside the box even if I manually set it's `height` and `width` to `100%`, nor does it work if I added the bootstrap class `img-fluid`. 
another error occures when importing and using images from the .scss file in my react app, check it out in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614451/react-sass-getting-an-error-when-importing-img-from-a-scss-file/53618002#53618002), thats it, thanks very much for your time

Comment: Have you run the code snippets to see if they work?

Comment: well, I didn't run it here to be honest, but I did provide a link to a working sample in codepen

Comment: The problem (at least in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXXLpG?editors=1100)) is your use of `flex-grow`. This property is designed to distribute free space in the container. Because the middle column has more free space (this column has two gaps, the other columns have one), the items will be smaller. Use `flex-basis` instead. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: thanks Michael, that helped, the question actually consists of two parts, and yeah the first part turned out to be duplicate but the second is not I guess, plus, I actually referred to another question I have at the end which nobody also answered, could you please consider checking that out and then maybe you want to unmark it duplicate, thanks

Comment: hello again Michael, could you please consider rereading my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

https://codepen.io/t_sg/pen/NEQayz

The HTML:

```
<section class="projects">
  <div  class="container fcontainer">
    <div class="fcol fcol--1">
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
      <div class="box box-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fcol fcol--2">
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fcol fcol--3">
      <div class="box box-2"></div>
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.fcontainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 30px;

  .fcol {
    color: #333;
    margin: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 60vh;
    flex-grow: 4;
  }
}

.box {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  &-1 {
    background: lightblue;
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-height: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  }

  &-2 {
    background: lightgreen;
    flex: 0 0 66.67%;
    max-height: calc(66.67% - 20px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly what I am trying to do :), I would appreciate if you can consider the 2nd part of the question too, related to putting an image in each box, avoiding image overflowing outside the of it. but thanks very much anyway :)